# Should the username and timestamp be migrated for changesets?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub, tfvc

The following text on the [OpsHub Migration Utility page](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2) indicates that the username and timestamp will be embedded in the comments of the migrated changeset.

> Metadata information about the source Change set like original username, original check-in timestamp are embedded in Change set comments during migration for Change sets.
>   https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2

Why am I not seeing this metadata embedded in the changeset comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature was moved to the commercial edition last November, I suspect they need to update the description on the visual studio gallery to reflect that change.

I have a batch of code you can run on your source server to copy the data into the changeset comment before migration:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace TfsChangesetCommentEnricher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
                new Uri("http://jessehouwing:8080/tfs/defaultcollection"));

            var vcs = collection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            var changes = vcs.QueryHistory(new ItemSpec("$/", RecursionType.Full));

            foreach (var change in changes)
            {
                if (!change.Comment?.Contains("\r\n\r\n-- \r\nOriginally checked-in") ?? true)
                {
                    change.Comment = string.Format(
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
@"{0}

-- 
Originally checked-in
* by: {1} ({2})
* on: {3:u}
* in: {5}
* id: {4}",
                        change.Comment,
                        change.Committer,
                        change.CommitterDisplayName,
                        change.CreationDate,
                        change.ChangesetId,
                        change.VersionControlServer.TeamProjectCollection.Uri);

                        change.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will update the source server's changesets and will embed the information prior to migration. That way the data successfully makes it across. I refused to pay $1500 per team project for this functionality.

See also

- https://jessehouwing.net/tfs-migration-work-around-pricy-features-of-opshub/

The new feature matrix is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this Jesse!