# Login to TFS 2010 as a different user in Source end point in opshub

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I have installed the free version of opshub. I would like to connect to tfs 2010 as the source endpoint in opshub as a different user. 
The issue is, it automatically uses my current AD credentials and connects to tfs 2010.
I removed the existing connection and re added the tfs but still uses my current ad credentials
I would like to connect as a different user.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try clearing the cache as explained in this link (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35785369) and then try to re-authenticate with the user that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Few things that i might have not mentioned.
I am running the migration from my laptop and TFS 2010 in on a aws instance.

There are no files in the cache folder, So i created a new ad user and added that user to tfs 2010 and removed my login from tfs 2010.
Then from my laptop, I switched to the new user that i created and ran the migration but the changeset still shows my name.
Is it because, I created the empty project in VSTS?
So does the tool uses VSTS or tfs 2010 login credentials for changeset?
To be noted I am using the free tool and all the changesets will not be migrated including the users. It only shows changeset so and so migrated by Goutam Rajput.

Comment: Yep that is correct. Free version uses the VSTS authenticated user as checckin user

Answer (score 0):

The tool uses VSTS credential to create the changeset. So all the changeset show the same name is an expected behavior. If you want to keep these information, you need to use commercial version, the information will be placed in the changeset comments.

> Due to the model/limitation of TFS itself, the Work item ID’s and
>   Change set ID’s of the migrated content in Visual Studio Online will
>   not match the Work item ID's and Change set ID's of the same content
>   in on premise TFS.  When using the commercial version metadata
>   information about the source Change set like original username,
>   original check-in timestamp are embedded in Change set comments during
>   migration for Change sets.

You can also try with the method in this question to keep these information: [Should the username and timestamp be migrated for changesets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202239/should-the-username-and-timestamp-be-migrated-for-changesets)